# .Click href based on value in html table

Tags: html, vba, excel

I need to `.Click` the href on line 2 of the HTML code below based on the value of line 12 in said code (Accrued Other Associate Wages) relative to a predefined value in my excel workbook.

Said differently, if cell in my workbook = "Accrued Other Associate Wages", then click the href that contains "Accrued Other Associate Wages" as a table attribute along the X axis).  Note that the particular webform I'm attempting to navigate is arranged as a table. Each "button" that I need to click on the Y axis has the same href inner text, but unique identifiers along the X axis.

```html
<td>
    <a tabindex="33" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_lnkReconcile" onclick="javascript:return CheckInterval();" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$assignedAccountsGrid$ctl00$ctl04$lnkReconcile','')">Reconcile</a>
</td>
<td>US</td>
<td>CORP</td>
<td>DOM</td>
<td>2202050</td>
<td>XX</td>
<td>XX</td>
<td>XX</td>
<td>0L</td>
<td>Accrued Other Associate Wages</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I was understanding you correctly.

Try this:

```
Sub clickIt()

    Dim ie As Object

    ' .... navigate and ensure page is fully loaded

    Dim myVal As String, objColl As Object, o As Object
    myVal = "Accrued Other Associate Wages" 'Whatever you are trying to click

    Set objColl = ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_lnkReconcile")
    Set objColl = objColl.getElementsByTagName("td")

    For Each o In objColl
        If o.InnerHTML Like "*" & myVal & "*" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    o.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: @K.Davis - Thank you for your response.  When I execute your suggested code, I'm getting Run-time error '91': "Object variable or With block variable not set." If I insert "MsgBox o Is Nothing" immediately above "o.Click,"  and run, the result in the message box is "True." Thanks for your help.